# Misuse of hamcrest hasItems

Tags: java, junit, hamcrest

I have a list of Integers (current) and I want to check whether this list contains all elements from list expected and not even one element from list notExpected, so code looks like:

```
    List<Integer> expected= new ArrayList<Integer>();
    expected.add(1);
    expected.add(2);

    List<Integer> notExpected = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    notExpected.add(3);
    notExpected.add(4);

    List<Integer> current = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    current.add(1);
    current.add(2);


    assertThat(current, not(hasItems(notExpected.toArray(new Integer[expected.size()]))));

    assertThat(current, (hasItems(expected.toArray(new Integer[expected.size()]))));
```

So long so good. But when I add

```
    current.add(3);
```

the test is also green. Do I misused the hamcrest matcher? 
Btw.

```
    for (Integer i : notExpected)
        assertThat(current, not(hasItem(i)));
```

gives me the correct answer, but I thought that I just can easily use the hamcrest matcher for that. I'm using junit 4.11 and hamcrest 1.3

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`hasItems(notExpected...)` would only match `current` if all elements from `notExpected` were also in `current`. So with the line

```
assertThat(current, not(hasItems(notExpected...)));
```

you assert that `current` doesn't contain **all elements** from `notExpected`.

One solution to assert that `current` doesn't contain **any elements** from `notExpected`:

```
assertThat(current, everyItem(not(isIn(notExpected))));
```

and then you don't even have to convert the list to array. This variant maybe a bit more readable, but requires conversion to array:

```
assertThat(current, everyItem(not(isOneOf(notExpected...))));
```

Note that these matchers are not from `CoreMatchers` in `hamcrest-core`, so you will need to add a dependency on `hamcrest-library`.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
    <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
</dependency>
```